# Makefile generic binaries compilations

Tags: makefile

I have a set of source files that share the same Makefile rule pattern:

```
bin1: bin1.o libfoo.a
    $(LDENV) $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

bin2: bin2.o libfoo.a
    $(LDENV) $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

bin3: bin3.o libfoo.a
    $(LDENV) $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

...
```

Now, how may I refactor this to avoid repeating the same rule over and over? This is easy if a file extension is added to the binaries:

```
%.out: %.o libfoo.a
    $(LDENV) $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

But is it possible to do the same without using one?

Comment: You said _this is easy if a file extension is added_, then asked _is it possible to do the same without using one_.  Why don't you just create a makefile using a pattern rule without using an extension, and see if it works?  It would have taken less time than it took to write this SO question (hint: yes, it will work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Static Pattern Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
bin1 bin2 bin3: %: %.o libfoo.a
    $(LDENV) $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

This way this is cleaner and you are sure that the `%` only match `bin1`, `bin2` and `bin3` targets (I think this is want you want).